# How can I trigger an event upon scrolling?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to trigger an event upon end of scrolling in my `mat-table`. This is what I have tried so far but event doesn't get triggered at all.

```
<div (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
  <table mat-table
         ....
  </table>
</div>
```

In my `ts` file,

```
onScroll(event: any) {
  console.log("----scrolling-----");
}
```

I even tried adding `@HotListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])` but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you trying to detect the window scrolling or scrolling inside the div?  (seems like you want the "(scroll)" on the element that is scrollable.)

Comment: scrolling inside the div

Comment: your code is working for me.  (I added an in-line style to make scrollbars appear: <div style="overflow: scroll; height: 100px;" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">....content bigger than 100px so scrollbar can be scrolled.. </div> )

Comment: That's odd. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: maybe copy/paste the actual code of the page.  From what you posted here, it doesn't seem like the DIV would have scrollbars at all.